# How do I bring my jackbox games on a trip Without bringing my home PC?

Tags: steam, streaming

In November, I'm taking a trip to my in-laws, and they recently got interested in Jackbox games.  They are almost certainly going to be interested in playing more of it when we take a trip there.  I would like to be able to play my 5 jackbox party packs with them.

The problem is, they aren't exactly 'trusting' of third party software like the Steam Client, and I don't have a very good laptop.  Even if I did, what I really want to do is stream the game to my parent's TV.

Is there some sort of cable setup I can do, preferably with my phone but if I need to use my laptop then I can as well, in order to stream my Steam Jackbox games to my in-laws' television?

Answer (score 5):

**Maybe.**

Here are your options as I see them:

**Persuade your in-laws to let you install Steam on their computer.**

Pros:

- Probably the most straightforward solution.
- Doesn't cost any money.

Cons:

- You have to convince your in-laws to go along with it.
- You have to log into Steam on someone else's computer, which is a minor security risk. Make sure you have enabled Steam Guard, don't reuse your Steam password on any other sites, and be sure to log out when you're done.
- You might have trouble hooking the computer to the TV, unless they're right next to each other.

**Try to run it on your laptop.**

Pros:

- Jackbox is not the most technically demanding series of games. Your laptop might handle it just fine, even if it's got a weak graphics chipset.
- Doesn't cost any money (assuming you already own a laptop).
- You can test it in advance to make sure it will play well, and pick a different solution if it doesn't.

Cons:

- Doesn't generalize to more demanding games.
- Requires you to bring your laptop, which might be inconvenient.
- If you have a really weak laptop, Jackbox might not run on it.

**Use a cloud gaming service such as GeForce Now**

Pros:

- Can be used to stream to any computer regardless of computing power.

Cons:

- Usually requires installing client software, which your in-laws might disapprove of (so use the laptop instead).
- Requires a strong internet connection with low latency. Usually performs better over a wired connection. For a game like Jackbox, this might not be such a big deal if you don't mind a little bit of lag.
- Costs money.
- You probably can't test your in-laws' internet in advance.

**Use [Steam Remote Play](https://store.steampowered.com/remoteplay#anywhere)**

Pros:

- Can be used to stream to any computer or Android/iOS device regardless of computing power.
- Doesn't cost any money.

Cons:

- Requires installing client software.
- Requires a strong internet connection for both your home computer and the device you want to use as a client.
- Your home computer must be turned on and running Steam, or else you must have some means of remotely turning it on when you want to play.
- You [may have to adjust your home router's settings](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/0689-74B8-92AC-10F2#networkports). Testing these settings may require leaving your home and using a different internet connection.

**Purchase a gaming laptop or a Nintendo Switch**

Pros:

- This gives you greater flexibility the next time you need to travel.
- The Switch has a lot of first-party exclusives, unlike other consoles. As a result, it is a good companion device for PC gamers (in my opinion).

Cons:

- Costs money.
- The Switch does in fact *have* at least some Jackbox games available on it, but you would need to buy them again.

Comment: You missed running on your PC at home and streaming it to the TV via the Steam app.

Comment: @OrangeDog: Added that.

Answer (score 1):

You can stream *Jackbox* games through Steam or even run them natively on a very weak laptop without a discrete GPU in my experience. You could also stream from a phone or tablet or an Android TV device as an alternative. You could connect the phone to the TV if your phone supports video over USB-C.